# Proper optimized way to monitor battery level in android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

I want to monitor the battery level and if it reaches certain level, i want to DO-SOMETHING. **What I am worried about is draining too much battery unnecessarily.**

Using a service will keep on running in the background. Also if i used android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED intent, it will check for every single change in the battery level. This two methods might drain unnecessary battery according to my requirements.

So, if I use AlarmManager(which is also a service handled by OS), it will check that battery level every user-defined(appropriate time).

The following are codes which I have implemented.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        mAlarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverTest.class);

        // User defined time
        long fiveMin= (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES/3); // adjustment here

        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                    System.currentTimeMillis()+fiveMin, oneMin, 
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    }

}
```

Broadcast receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiverTest extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent arg1) {

    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = pContext.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

    int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
    int percent = (level*100)/scale;

    if(percent== myThreshold)
        //DO-SOMETHING
}
```

}

In manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiverTest">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Permission:

```
android.permission.BATTERY_STATS
```

Since its a repeating alarm, it will keep on checking even if the application is closed.

eg.: DO-SOMETHING: might be lock the application if the application was already opened **OR** not allowed to open the application if it was already closed.

**Is this the proper way to do and is my understanding correct?**
Kindly suggest me if there is any other proper way to do.

**EDITED:**

**If I were to check the battery level for every 5-10 hours of interval, what would be the best way to do so?**

Comment: Why did people downvote this? @Sats answer worked great for what I need it for..

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use AlarmManager class . Your application consumes more battery if you use AlarmManager class.

The easiest way to do it is using a broadcast listener for the intent ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.

```
public class AlarmReceiverTest extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int batteryLevel = intent.getIntExtra(
                    BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            int maxLevel = intent
                    .getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 0);
            int batteryHealth = intent.getIntExtra(
                    BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH,
                    BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN);
            float batteryPercentage = ((float) batteryLevel / (float) maxLevel) * 100;

            // Do something with batteryPercentage and batteryHealth.
            // batteryPercentage here ranges 0-100
        }
    }
```

**onReceive runs every time the battery level changes.**

In your main activity register the broadcast receiver:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AlarmReceiverTest mBatteryLevelReceiver = new AlarmReceiverTest();
    registerReceiver(mBatteryLevelReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}
```

Comment: I also agree that AlarmManager is not necessary - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED is not called very frequently. It is also worth repeating that as per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED this receiver must be registered in code and not in manifest.

Comment: so, if I don't unregister this broadcast, it will keep on running continously on battery changed even after the application is closed?

Comment: yes , if you want to stop it ,use this: @Override
public void onDestroy(){
       super.onDestroy();
       unregisterReceiver(mBatteryLevelReceiver);
}

Comment: what does battery health do here? And BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH:  current health constant & BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN : constant 1 really mean?

Comment: for more detials: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

Comment: @Droid_Lover when I use your code, the broadcast receiver is firing for every 20-25seconds if the power is not plugged in, and its fired for every 15secods if the power is plugged in, can you explain me why is it behaving like that? i think its going to drain the battery.

Comment: @kaze , this broadcast fire whenever battery level changes, don't worry this does not draining too much battery.

Comment: @Droid_Lover ok, but if I were to check the battery level for every 5hours of interval, can you tell me please tell me what would be the best way to-do so?

Comment: @kaze , use AlarmManager , the only best way for scheduling task .

Comment: @Droid_Lover hi, I have found 1 more issue, if I close the application or kill the activity where I registered the broadcast  , the broadcast receiver is no longer running. How can I handle this? I want to run the broadcast receiver always once it has been registered.

Comment: @Tootsie_Roll register the receiver inside a Service class, onReceive(Context, Intent) will run as long as the Service is running.

Comment: @OnePunchMan did you find a solution for this Issue ? the same thing happens to me... when the activity us killed it stops monitoring my battery.